# Ubuntu 14.04 cannot shutdown after kernel update

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel, shutdown

Today the software updater reminded me to update the hardware support, and I clicked "install". Then it installed the new Linux kernel: `4.4.0-37-generic`. Before I updated, the kernel was `3.19.0-66-generic`.

Everything was OK after reboot. But when I try to shutdown my computer again, it cannot. It stays at the splash screen with the text "Ubuntu", and 5 dots. So I have to shutdown by pushing the button.

In order to see the processes during shutdown, I modified the file `/etc/default/grub`, changing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` into `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nosplash"`. So when I shutdown, I saw the information as follows:

```
it-for-state stop/waiting
  Stopping rsync daemon rsync
  speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
  Asking all remaining processes to terminate...
  All processes ended within 1 seconds...
ModemManager[826]: <info> Caught signal, shutting down...
ModemManager[826]: <info> ModemManageris shut down
nm-dispatcher.action: Caught signal 15, shutting down...
  Deactivating swap...
  Unmounting local filesystems...
  Will now halt
[ 1072.126530] NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s! [halt:6067]
[ 1100.127158] NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s! [halt:6067]
[ 1123.927692] INFO: rcu_sched self-detected stall on CPU
[ 1123.927728] o0-...: (14999 ticks this GP) idle=c63/140000000000001/0 softirq=21534/21534fqs=14998
[ 1123.927779] o (t=15000 jiffies g=16265 c=16264 q=24)
[ 1148.128235] NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 23s! [halt:6067]
[ 1176.128863] NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s! [halt:6067]
```

What should I do to solve this problem and make my system shutdown normally?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Intel CPU's? If so, start Synaptic from the dash, and install `intel-microcode` and `linux-firmware`.

1. start Synaptic from the dash
2. click the RELOAD icon
3. enter one filename into the search box
4. when the filename appears in the results pane, select it for install
5. click the APPLY button
6. repeat for the second filename

Let us know if that solves your problem.

Cheers, Al